# Commandblock Output = False not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a command set as follows:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[Level 10] Medium ","color":"green","bold":true,"clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/setblock 479.5 13 309.5 redstone_block 1"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Click to Play"}]}}},{"text":"[BOSS] ","color":"light_purple","bold":true}]
```

Which will show a clickable message in chat, which when clicked will place a block, however I do not want any output in chat. I have done:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

However after cliking the text, the following can be seen in chat:

> Block Placed

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Nice name Grandmmar Police!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the tellraw the server acts as if the player has run the command. Therefor you will want to disable `sendCommandFeedback`.

So use this command

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

This will hide the message.

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't realize this was a thing :P